# Automatic baking followed by a render for animation

Tags: rendering, animation, scripting, keyframes, baking

I'm looking forward on making an animated movie of 2 hours and the challenge are these "Animated Maps (Normal map, Specular map)" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mc7ADD4b8_0. I want the animations in the movie to be quite accurate which means that the maps would change on the model on pretty much every frame depending on how each model is animated. Is there a way for the maps to be baked, then assigned on the model and then render the scene and all of that to be done automatically for every frame by the program by clicking "Render" only once (it pretty much seems like everybody's dream though)?

The maps would be baked on the lower poly model who's rig is a duplicate of the other that is assigned on the higher poly one.

Comment: Not sure if this would actually be faster or slower than rendering with the high-poly model..

Comment: gandalf3@ The idea is not to click bake and then put the maps on each frame and the render speed doesn't matter since I'm not going to be around the computer. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Well, yes, I imagine this could be done fairly easily with python. But I'm not convinced that the total render time would benefit from using normal maps if you are re-baking them every frame. It might be better to use the high poly model, which will give you a slightly higher-poly result. (no low-poly edge artifacts)

Comment: gandalf3@ What you're saying is, the render time will take faster with the high poly models than what I'm aiming for?

Comment: gandalf3@ If you mean, to use traditional maps (non animatible), then the problem is that the facial expressions will have wrinkles, which would be visualized by the animated maps. By the way, how would this be done with python (totally new to coding)